pgn-extract adding a FEN tag/header to each PGN
I've been using pgn-extract to compile a PGN file acting as a collection of opening positions. It has th ability to add the FEN of the final position to he end of each PGN, but for my purposes with this file, I need the FEN to be written as a header/tag.
Current Result:
[Event "N/A"]
[Site "lichess.com"]
[Date ""]
[Round "N/A"]
[White "N/A"]
[Black "N/A"]
[Result "*"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. g3 Be7 5. Bg2 O-O 6. O-O
{ "rnbq1rk1/ppp1bppp/4pn2/3p4/2PP4/5NP1/PP2PPBP/RNBQ1RK1 b - - 4 6" } *

Desired Result:
[Event "N/A"]
[Site "lichess.com"]
[Date ""]
[Round "N/A"]
[White "N/A"]
[Black "N/A"]
[Result "*"]
[FEN"FEN_STRING_HERE"]

If anyone knows a way to add the FEN of the final position a multiple files/games at once to the heading using pgn-extract or something else, please let me know. Thanks.

A problem with that functionality is that a FEN tag in the header of a game is used to indicate the starting position for the game. So adding such a tag with the final position would invalidate the game.

What I came up with was a google spreadsheet Substitute command to change the "{}" to "[]" and reordering the comment to a tag. If anyone has anything more elegant, let me know, but for file of just about 80 games, it did the trick without too much hassle.
